# Appium c# how to use 1 adb server with multi appium server for several devices

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I use appium and build tool to testing, but with multi devices, appium always create multi adb instances, I find a solution which can run multi appium server with only 1 adb instance.

Can everyone have idea ???